# How to hide multiple divs by their id and class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  want  to  hide multiple divs  id  by using javascript .i am trying to have the 5 divs to be hidden on page load but can not seem to get it to work. I can use Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: What 5 divs? First five or last five?

Comment: Assign a same class to all those div and use the class selector to hide them.

Comment: No 2 elements should have same id. id's are unique. Use class istead. And then use class selector to hide  like `$(".mYClass").hide()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common class for all the divs you want to hide, once you have got the `divs` you want hhidden, loop over the elements to hide them..

```js
function foo() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.hideMe');
  divs.forEach((eachDiv) => {
    eachDiv.style.display = 'none';
    //eachDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="hideMe">One</div>
<div class="hideMe">Two</div>
<div class="hideMe">Three</div>

<button onclick="foo()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to hide multiple div with different ids like this: (separate them with spaces)

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3, #id4, #id5').hide()
```

But this is generally a bad solution. I suggest you to add a common class to them and just hide them when required:

```
$('.common-class').hide()
```